# Django: request.is_ajax() returning False

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm trying to make the search of 'patient' Dynamic with ajax. Every thing in my code is working well but I don't know wy request.is_ajax() always returns false. I search about it but I didn't find the solution yet, right now my code do the search but with changing of the url and that mean the js dosen't work. I don't know how work well with javascript in Django so please help me.
**This is my views.py:**

```
def index(request):

    ctx = {}
    url_parameter = request.GET.get("q")
    
    if url_parameter:
        queryset = Patient.objects.annotate(fullname=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name'))
        patients = queryset.filter(fullname__icontains=url_parameter)
        #patients = Patient.objects.filter(name__icontains=url_parameter)
    else:
        patients = Patient.objects.all()

    ctx["patients"] = patients
    print(request.is_ajax())
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string(template_name="patient/patients-results-partial.html",context={"patients": patients})
        data_dict = {"html_from_view": html}

        return JsonResponse(data=data_dict, safe=False)
    return render(request, "patient/index.html", context=ctx)
```

**index.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">


    {# part added for dynamic search#}
    {# icon and search-box #}
    <form class="form-inline">
      <i id="search-icon" class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input id="patient-input" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q">
    </form>

    {# artist-list section #}
    <div id="replaceable-content" class="col-6">
      {% include 'patient/patients-results-partial.html' %}
    </div>


    
  </div>

    

  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
    <a href="{% url 'register_patient' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter un nouveau patient</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Téléphone</th>
            <th>Sexe</th>
            <th>Date de naissance</th>
            <th>Docteur</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for field in patients %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{field.first_name}}</td>
              <td>{{field.last_name}}</td>
              <td>{{field.phone}}</td>
              <td>{{field.sex}}</td>
              <td>{{field.birth_date}}</td>
              <td>{{field.doctor}}</td>
              <td><a href="{{field.id}}/" class="btn btn-warning">Details</a></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and this is my js code:

```
const patient_input = $("#patient-input");
const search_icon = $('#search-icon');
const patients_div = $('#replaceable-content');
const endpoint = '/patient/';
const delay_by_in_ms = 700;
let scheduled_function = false;

let ajax_call = function (endpoint, request_parameters) {
    $.getJSON(endpoint, request_parameters)
        .done(response => {
            // fade out the patients_div, then:
            patients_div.fadeTo('slow', 0).promise().then(() => {
                // replace the HTML contents
                patients_div.html(response['html_from_view'])
                // fade-in the div with new contents
                patients_div.fadeTo('slow', 1)
                // stop animating search icon
                search_icon.removeClass('blink')
            })
        })
}


patient_input.on('keyup', function () {

    const request_parameters = {
        q: $(this).val() // value of patient_input: the HTML element with ID patient-input
    }

    // start animating the search icon with the CSS class
    search_icon.addClass('blink')

    // if scheduled_function is NOT false, cancel the execution of the function
    if (scheduled_function) {
        clearTimeout(scheduled_function)
    }

    // setTimeout returns the ID of the function to be executed
    scheduled_function = setTimeout(ajax_call, delay_by_in_ms, endpoint, request_parameters)
})
```

Comment: [`Request.is_ajax()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) only looks for a specific value in a specific header. `$.getJSON()` likely doesn't send that header.

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of AJAX call, is clean and easier than what you have in your code.
This model AJAX is working for me.
Maybe this js code helps you to fix your bug.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = $(this);
    const submit_btn = form.find('#submit-button');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your URL for send ajax call',
        type: 'POST', // Method of call, such as POST or GET
        data: 'data as JSON', // You can use 'form.serialize()' to
        beforeSend: function () {
            // This line calls before that AJAX is called.
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // If the back-end returns a JSON response with 200 status code, js will run this line.
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // If the back-end returns a JSON response with 400 status code, js will run this line.
        },
        complete: function () {
            // After success or error is called , this function will be called
        },
    })
})
```

Comment: Please can you more explain to me because like I told you I'm new in javascript and especially how to implement js code in django project

Comment: I will update this code with more detail, but for more information, you can see the documentation page about AJAX in jquery website. [document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)